# Always get latest record for a user when grouping: SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a postgres table that looks like this:

```
user_id date          val
1       2015-01-01    1
2       2015-01-01    2
1       2015-01-30    7
3       2015-02-01    1
3       2015-02-05    7
3       2015-02-12    3
4       2015-02-10    1
4       2015-02-11    2
```

I want to be able to group by month getting the sum of vals such that it only calculates sums with a users latest value.

Expected output:

```
date         sum
2015-01-01   9
2015-02-01   5
```

I am hoping there is something flexible that allows the use of the same code to aggregate in different ways. So if I decide to group by user_id

```
user_id   sum
1         7
3         3
4         2
```

I can think of some complicated SQL joining based on max etc. But I am wondering if there is something more elegant?

Comment: it is the latest value not the max value. So the latest value for february user_id = 3 is 3 and the latest value for february user_id = 4 is 2

Answer (score 0):

Sum max per month:

```
-- sum the inner max values using only the date to group by
select d, sum(maxV) as sumMaxV
from
(
    SELECT DISTINCT  -- needed to trim down results from partition
    date_trunc('month',dated) as d,
    first_value(val) OVER ( -- only the first result is taken for each partition, they are 
                            -- identical due to ordering, hence we need distinct them
        PARTITION BY date_trunc('month',dated), user_id     
        ORDER BY val DESC) as maxV   
    FROM T
) tmp
group by d
```

Result:

```
d                      sumMaxV
2015-01-01T00:00:00Z      9
2015-02-01T00:00:00Z      9
```

---

Sum the last per month:

```
-- sum the inner lastV values using only the date to group by
select d, sum(lastV) as sumLastV
from
(
    SELECT DISTINCT   
    date_trunc('month',dated) as d,
    first_value(val) OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY date_trunc('month',dated), user_id     
        ORDER BY dated DESC) as lastV   
    FROM T
) tmp
group by d
```

Output:

```
d                      sumlastv
2015-01-01T00:00:00Z      9
2015-02-01T00:00:00Z      5
```

---

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE T  ("user_id" int, "dated" timestamp, "val" int);    
INSERT INTO T   ("user_id", "dated", "val")
VALUES          (1, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 1),
                (2, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 2),
                (1, '2015-01-30 00:00:00', 7),
                (3, '2015-02-01 00:00:00', 1),
                (3, '2015-02-05 00:00:00', 7),
                (3, '2015-02-12 00:00:00', 3),
                (4, '2015-02-10 00:00:00', 1),
                (4, '2015-02-11 00:00:00', 2);
```

Comment: thanks -- looking to group by the latest values not the max values

Comment: @eljusticiero67 added sum for last of month as well.

Comment: and changed to use `date_trunc` instead of `substr(cast (dated as varchar(20)) ,1 , 7)` - which should help using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Following lets you group by users or dates (inspiration from @Patrick Artner's solution)

```
-- split date to year, month
with dd as(
select user_id, extract(year from dates) as yyyy,
      extract(month from dates) as mm, val
from mytable),
-- get the latest value per user_id, year and month
aggs as(
select distinct user_id, yyyy, mm, 
  last_value(val) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, yyyy, mm ORDER BY yyyy, mm) as latest
from dd
) 
-- group by either user_id or date
select user_id, -- concat(yyyy, '-',mm, '-01')::date, 
sum(latest) as total
from aggs
group by 1;
```